# How to add report to Inventory Transfers dropdown menu for reports

Tags: acumatica

I'd like to add a report to the dropdown menu of the Inventory Transfers screen.  After searching Stack Overflow, I found the following example, but as it seemingly always happens, it doesn't seem to apply to this screen (the example is for the APPaymentEntry BLC):

```
 public class APPaymentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APPaymentEntry> 

 {
     public override void Initialize()
     {
         Base.action.AddMenuAction(ShowURL);
     }

      public PXAction<APPayment> ShowURL;
     [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Print Remittance")]
     [PXButton]
     protected virtual void showURL()
     {
         APPayment doc = Base.Document.Current;
         if (doc.RefNbr != null)
         {
              throw new PXReportRequiredException(doc, "AP991000", null);
         }
     }
 }
```

There is no Base.action.AddMenuAction  method for the graph extension for INTransferEntry.

How can I add a report to launch to this menu for Inventory Transfers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience, the **Actions** button is usually represented by the **action** BLC member and the **Reports** button is represented by the **report** BLC member.

The following code snippet should add a report to the Inventory Transfers dropdown menu for reports:

```
public class INTransferEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<INTransferEntry>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Base.report.AddMenuAction(ShowCustomReport);
    }

    public PXAction<INRegister> ShowCustomReport;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Show Custom Report")]
    protected void showCustomReport()
    {
        INRegister doc = Base.transfer.Current;
        if (doc != null && doc.RefNbr != null)
        {
            throw new PXReportRequiredException(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, Ruslan!  ;D